# A word that refers to something that had lasted most of one's life?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

> She wants to get rid of an affliction that had been haunting her
>   most of her life.

I was thinking if I could make the passage above shorter, say using an adjective instead of *that had been haunting her
 most of her life.*

Is there any adjective I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could say  “had been a life-long burden” instead of “had been haunting her most of her life”, and it would read ok.

Also consider replacing “an affliction that had been haunting her most of her life” with “a long-burdensome affliction”.

Note that “She wants to getting rid of” is grammatically wrong.    “She wants to get rid of” is grammatically ok.  Also note, “get rid of” could be replaced by  “allay”,  “alleviate”, or similar:

> She wants to allay a long-burdensome affliction.

More figuratively, and also closer to cliché (and implying rather than explicitly saying she wants to remove the affliction), one could write:

> A horrible affliction had long been her cross.

Comment: @jwpat7 Is it lifelong or life-long? I'm confused.

Comment: @janoChen, wiktionary (for example) lists *[life-long](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/life-long)* and *[life long](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/life_long)* as alternative spellings of *[lifelong](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lifelong)*.  Note, [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=life%20-%20long,life%20long,lifelong&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0) indicates that *life-long* is most common, *lifelong* much less so but on its way up, and *life long* is rarely used.  Take your pick and then be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

You also could use the term *[perennial](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/perennial?q=perennial)*

> lasting or existing for a long or apparently infinite time; enduring or continually recurring

Another possibility is *[enduring](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/enduring?q=enduring)*

> continuing or long-lasting:

Your construction could be

> She seeks to be free of her *perennial* [or *enduring*] affliction.

Comment: _Perennial_ usually refers specifically to annual recurrence or surviving the winter. I don't think it has the right connotation for a long-term affliction.

Comment: @Bradd: _perennial_ might work if the affliction was one that occurred in quasi-regular outbreaks, as opposed to being always existent.

Comment: @J.R. Yes, that would make more sense. _Perennial_ is about periodicity.

Answer (score 2):

Persistent is a good adjective, though it does not convey life-long. I agree that enduring makes sense in that context.